# Php not returning any data from sql database even though database has data in it

Tags: php, mysqli, count

I am new to PHP and learning how to retrieve data from a database into html. I have created a database in go-daddy with a simple test table called "Fruits" with four rows and 3 columns and it has data in it.  When I try to pull the data into html, it seems like there is no data in it (or php is not reading the data). Is able to count the number of rows properly (4) and return that, but when I count the values in the table, it says 0.  So when I try to later use the fetch_array command, nothing is outputting.  Any advise anyone can provide is much appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
echo "<p>PHP is enabled</p>";
$host="localhost";
$user="me";
$password="mypassword";
$dbname = "TestDB";
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname) or die("Couldn't 
connect to server.");
$query = "SELECT * FROM Fruits";

if ($result=mysqli_query($cxn,$query)){
    // Return the number of rows in result set
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);

    //Return the number of values in result set
    $size=array_count_values($result);
    printf("Result set has %d values.\n",$size);

    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    }

mysql_close($cxn);

?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to accomplish with array_count_values(). Am I correct in saying you want to output the number of instances of each value in the row of Fruits? i.e. 2 Apples, 2 Oranges?

Comment: [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) returns an array, not a number, so printing it with `%d` will not work. Maybe you meant to use `$size=count(array_count_values($result))` instead. You might also need to put a call to [`$result->fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) in between.